# Event Fees display as total of contribution when they should not

Tags: contributions

Is there a way to have events not total into a contact's contributions?  I want to register people for events but each time I do and use event fee it shows the running total in contributions which is not correct for our usage case.

I see contributions as donations so I don't want fees from events (in this case a theater production) to show as a contribution (donation) for tax purposes.

Any ideas?  I have tried to change how the funds are

Comment: I understand the distinction you want to make in terms of separating event and donation income but am not quite clear when and how you want to display it. But also be aware that "contribution" in CiviCRM language means any income associated with a contact. If you really wanted to use the word contribution in a more restricted sense you might have to do some additional language translations but that might be messy.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1. Make your events free in civicrm but I assume that is not what you want
2. Differentiate in your reports between financial types. CiviCRM has Financial type system to register event fees with the type event fee, and donation with the type donation. You can also add other financial types.

See the manual: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/key-concepts-and-configurations/#financial-types-financial-accounts-and-accounting-codes

Answer (score 0):

You could also set up Summary Fields then you have any easy 'count' happening for all your Donations and exclude Event fees based on your settings in Summary Fields.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are based, but in the UK, the Gift Aid extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/gift-aid-extension-uk is designed to deal with the tax differences for different sorts of income. Even is you are elsewhere it might be worth looking at it to see if it will work for you.